# Access Fragment's TextView (inside a viewpager) from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, textview

As the title says, I am trying to access (setText,etc) a TextView thats inside a fragment. The fragment is loaded into a viewpager in an activity. I want to access this TextView from the activity class.

```
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager pager;
FragmentPageOne fragPageOne;
FragmentPageTwo fragPageTwo;
```

Exert of Activity's onCreate:

```
fragPageOne= new FragmentPageOne();
fragPageTwo = new FragmentPageTwo();

mPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), 
    fragPageOne.getClass(), fragPageTwo.getClass(),
);
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.eventPager);
pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

ViewPagerAdapter class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Class<? extends Fragment>> fragmentsClasses;
    private final Context context;

    public EventViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, Class<? extends Fragment>... fragmentsClasses) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.fragmentsClasses = Arrays.asList(fragmentsClasses);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, fragmentsClasses.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentsClasses.size();
    }
}
```

FragmentPageOne class (FragmentPageTwo's structure is similar.):

```
public class FragmentPageOne extends Fragment {

    public View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_1, container, false);

        return (LinearLayout) rootView;
    }
}
```

I am getting a null pointer (obviously) when i try to use this (within the activity itself):

```
TextView text = (TexView) pager.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
text.setText("hello world);
```

Answer (score 0):

get your current fragment :

```
 public Fragment getVisibleFragment(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
        if(fragments != null){
            for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
                if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                    return fragment;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

then get the view of the fragment to use findViewById from this view.

Comment: I tried. It still gives the same error however. I called: 
`View current = getVisibleFragment().getView();

        TextView text = (TextView) current.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        text.setText("asdf");`

Comment: Any idea with mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907625/why-is-accessing-textview-of-a-fragment-inside-activity-throwing-an-error

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet is to do this in the instantiateItem override method in the pager adapter like so;

```
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Activity activity;
    private int[] layouts;

    public WalletViewPagerAdapter(int[] layouts , Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.layouts =layouts;
        }
    @Override  
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        if (position ==0) {
            TextView availableBalance = view.findViewById(R.id.available);
            availableBalance.setText("N100,0000,000");

        }
        container.addView(view);  

        return view;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The view you're trying to access is not yet available as at the time you're calling it. Try overriding the onViewCreated method then use the view parameter to get textView like so;

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

TextView availableBalance = view.findViewById(R.id.available);
        availableBalance.setText("N100,0000,000");

}
```